# Post Condition Failed on Sitecore 10 CD (Content Delivery) server

Tags: content-delivery

I am getting the following error on our CD server and am unsure why. I tried a few solutions I found online, however I am currently just trying stuff at this point in order for it to work, but am not getting a step closer to fixing the issue.

I am getting the following:

> Post condition failed
>
> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception** Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed

> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed]
> Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull(T result, String message)
> +85    Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name) +86    Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabases() +121    Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerLinkDataProviderFactory.CreateProvidersForAllDatabases()
> +161
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
> an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
> target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +269
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> +146    Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallStaticMethod(String typeName, String methodName, Object[] parameters) +165
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromFactoryMethod(XmlNode
> configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +534
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
> String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +91
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
> String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode
> configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +161
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
> configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +114
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
> String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
> String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath,
> String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
> Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetLinkDatabase() +36
> Sitecore.DefaultGlobals.Load() +294    (Object , Object ) +55
> Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
> Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
> PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
> +236    Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
> Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +146
> Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +898
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
> MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context) +277
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
> appContext) +369
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
> of an invocation.]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
> +111    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) +724

Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be?